# How to start JACK server on Ubuntu?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, jack, ardour

I discovered that I am not able to start JACK server on my desktop running Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS, which prevents me from running Ardour. I have tried a few things, which I found on Ask Ubuntu, but without any success, e.g. I tries killing pulseaudio and starting it using qjackctl.

I receive an error message:

```
D-BUS: JACK server could not be started. Sorry
Cannot connect to server secket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
```

Any suggestions how to resolve the issue?

Many thanks